# Место частицы БЫ в предложении

Tags: сослагательное-наклонение

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно сказать, что то, что частица **БЫ** стоит после слова "никогда" (а не после глагола в сослагательном наклонении), добавляет этому слову большую выразительность, эмфазу? Или я ошибаюсь?

> С анонимщиками именно так и следовало обращаться, **хотя она никогда бы не поступила так умышленно**, в силу своей принадлежности к классу.

Answer (score 1):

Частица [**БЫ**](http://www.fio.ru/tables/munia/razryady-chastits-po-znacheniyu/) относится к разряду формообразующих (образует условное наклонение).

Сослагательное наклонение выражается аналитически с помощью частицы **бы (б)**.
К сослагательному наклонению относятся сочетания частицы **бы (б)**, в том числе в составе союза **чтоб(ы)** и устаревших союзов **дабы** и **кабы**:
с формами прошедшего времени глагола (*увидела бы, чтобы увидела*);
с инфинитивами (*унести бы, чтобы увидеть*);
с предикативами (*надо бы, лучше бы*);
в составе эллиптических конструкций с существительными в косвенных падежах (*пирожка бы; тебя б на мое место*); 
с причастиями (редко, ненормативно: *показавшийся бы*); с деепричастиями (очень редко, ненормативно: *не достигнув бы цели*); с императивами (очень редко, ненормативно: *случись бы что*).

Частица *бы (б)* является энклитикой, то есть не имеет собственного ударения и примыкает к предыдущему слову; в некоторых случаях это отражается на письме (как в союзе *чтобы*). Чаще всего частица *бы (б)* занимает либо второе место в предложении, либо место после предиката.

«…будучи теснейшим образом связана по смыслу со сказуемым, она [частица *бы*] тем не менее и ныне может уходить от него **сколь угодно далеко влево** [выделено мной. — Р. М.]. Наследием вакернагелевского статуса является также запрет на дистантную постпозицию к сказуемому (возможна только контактная постпозиция); например, невозможно *Он от этого отказался наотрез бы* – при том, что и после *он*, и после *этого*, и после *отказался* частицу *бы* здесь поставить можно» [Зализняк 2008: 268].
[3.1 Место частицы бы (б) в предложении](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу тут усиления. Вообще по грамматике "бы" относится к глаголу, даже если этот глагол опущен или связь с ним потеряна (как в союзе "чтобы").  Поэтому игра с перемещением частицы по фразе не должна как-то существенно влиять ни на смысл, ни на акценты. Это скорее свойство авторского стиля.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!! Скажите пожалуйста: если Вы произносили бы это предложение, Вы сделали бы ударение на слово "никогда" или "поступила"?

Comment: @Anonym нет, не сделал бы, ни там ни там. Сделал бы на *умышленно*. Чтобы "ударять" на другие слова надо знать или контекст, или хотя бы ход мысли автора (тоже в общем-то контекст, но узкий).

Comment: Спасибо еще раз! я не носитель языка поэтому тяжело знать как правильно

Comment: @Anonym, ну для "неносителя" вы очень неплохо излагаете мысль. Не скромничайте, всё не так и трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Частица ***бы*** сама по себе и придаёт глаголу сослагательное наклонение. В усилении выразительности данная частица замечена не была)